# Serve a file outside servers public scope to client with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've some files placed inside an upload folder which is not accessible without privileges and is outside from servers public scope.
If the owner want to download the previously uploaded file I need to pipe the file. That for I thought [Streaming](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) is the right way but I can't get it work.
So my actually working solution is the following example.
Is this still correct?

```
APP.fs.readFile(media.path, function(error, file) {
    if (error === null) {
    res.type(media.type);
    res.send(file);
} else {
    self.Component.send404(res);
}
});
```

Comment: If the files are relatively small it could work, but streaming would be better. How did you implement it, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried it with fs.readStream and res.pipe(stream)

Comment: Try `stream.pipe(res)` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot that was working